# A functional equation with an inequality

Tags: functional-equations, functional-inequalities

I have an increasing function on $[0,1]$, $p \mapsto \Pi(p)$, that has the following properties.
$$\Pi(0) = 1 - \Pi(1) = 0$$
$$\Pi(p) + \Pi(1-p) < 1 \quad \forall{p} \in (0,1)$$
$$\Pi(p) > p \quad \forall{p} \in (0,\varepsilon)$$
where $0 < \epsilon < 0.5$ is a given small number. Furthermore, $\Pi$ is smooth.

Is it possible to characterize the class of functions that satisfy these properties beyond these functional relations?

Comment: Your title includes the phrase "functional equation" but I don't see any actual *equations* other than the values of $\Pi(0)$ and $\Pi(1)$. Are the inequalities all you have?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yes those are the only two equalities I have.

Comment: My gut says these conditions aren't strong enough to tell us very much -- your function can flap about a lot while still satisfying them, at least if $\varepsilon$ is small -- but I would advise you not to trust my gut very much. Example: suppose $\varepsilon=0.1$; let $\Pi(p)=2p$ for $0\leq p<0.1$, $\Pi(p)=0.2$ for $0.1\leq p<1$, $\Pi(1)=1$. Of course that's not smooth, so smooth it out a bit. And now almost any smallish perturbation of $\Pi$ will leave those conditions satisfied.